# This is my loop and trans.length=9

Tags: java

This is what is in trans:
(1,1,x)
(1,2,y)
(2,3,x)
(3,3,x)
(3,4,y)
(4,4,x)
(4,5,z)
(5,5,x)
(5,2,a)

This is my loop and trans.length=9

```
for(int i = 0; i < trans.length; i++)
{       
    table[trans[i].charAt(1)][trans[i].charAt(3)]+= trans[i].charAt(5);
}
```

This is my error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 49

What am I missing here? There must be something obvious!!

here is the table definition

```
table = new String[states][states];


for(int i =0; i < states; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < states-1; j++)
            {
                table[i][j]="";
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the 'table', is that also an array?

Comment: table is two dimensional array

Comment: Then have you check is the table throwing the exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: Before the loop, add System.out.println(table.length+" "+table[0].length); Is the table 256 x 256 or what size?

Comment: Better yet, add the definition of table.

Comment: Yes - Why 5x5 (states = 5)   Should it be  int states = 256.

Comment: states is entered in by the user. It is 5 in this case

Comment: @ChuckFricano that is why it is so perplexing that the error is at index 49, because it doesnt get close to 49

Comment: table[x][y] is going to give you this error when x or y > 5.

Comment: but its not going to be greater than 5. it gives me that error when x = 1 and y = 2. It goes through the loop once fine and on the second loop when i =1, it gives this error and says that the index is 49?

Comment: oh the ascii value for 1 is 49...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just use `charAt(..)` on String arrays giving a char and expect to gave the equivalent integer value without any conversion. It'll return the character code, which is wildly different. You should use something like `Character.getNumericValue(char)`, although maybe you should refactor the code.

Comment: when i print the values of trans[i].charAt(1),trans[i].charAt(3)], and trans[i].charAt(5) within the loop, I get what is expected once, then I get the error on the second loop. And the error says the out of bounds error is at index 49???

Comment: Use `element.split(",")` on the stuff within `(`and `)` at various points in the string, then read the array indices.

i.e., You need to find a `(`, then find the next matching `)`, then put that into `element.substring(beginindex, endindex)`, which gives you the string to use with `split(..)`. Keep doing this for the length of the initial string: `(1,1,x) (1,2,y) (2,3,x) (3,3,x) (3,4,y) (4,4,x) (4,5,z) (5,5,x) (5,2,a)`.

Comment: Actually, it might be possible to split on the blank space between elements -- i.e.: `)` and `(`.